# Unable to instantiate H2

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I am trying to setup H2 as in-memory database. I have configured it as :

```
spring:
  profiles: qa
  datasource:
    #url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "public"
    jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lisdashboard
    username: '@lisdashboard.db.username@'
    password: '@lisdashboard.db.password@'
  h2:
    console:
      path: /admin/h2-console
```

However I am getting this error when I try to run it

```
- Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.h2.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lisdashboard
-

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
- Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: 

Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.h2.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lisdashboard
```

I am not sure why it doesn't accept the jdbc url, Is there any issue in the format of my confg?

Comment: The exception message seems clear `claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lisdashboard`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a MySQL jdbc url to try to connect to an H2 instance.

You need to replace your configuration to use the url `jdbc:h2:mem:` instead of the one you are using now `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lisdashboard`.

If you want to use a different type of H2 instance, check the [documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url) to see the alternatives (such a file instance).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use H2 your config should look like:

```
spring:
  profiles: qa
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "public"
    username: '@lisdashboard.db.username@'
    password: '@lisdashboard.db.password@'
  h2:
    console:
      path: /admin/h2-console
```

You had a # infront of the URL and # is a comment in YAML